# filter lucene search based on a particular filed

Tags: lucene

I want to return all matched documents found after a document with a certain value. The value is unique.
I have tried to use numericfilterrange.  Thisis not a good solution as the field values may be in any orders

Answer (score 1):

Using a numeric range is the correct way to accplish what you want, if I understand what you need.  In order to sort on the same field, you'll need to pass a [`Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) argument to your search call, something like:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("myNumericField", SortField.Type.INT));
searcher.search(query, maxDocs, sort)
```

Comment: I need to retain all values after a certain value has been encountered in the search. For example, all documents, after a certain document containing field, "id" with value "5"

Comment: So, all documents with `id > 5`, right?  Unless I misunderstand your question, you say you were already getting that with a `NumericRangeQuery`.  Use the same query, and add a `Sort` as indicated.

Comment: Wait, rereading, maybe you are asking for something else.  Are you trying to, in effect, find a Document, then return all Document which were written to the index after that one?  Lucene documents don't really have a meaningful natural order, simply basing this on DocID is not really adequate.  If that's what you want, you should have a field related to it.  A datetime of entry might make sense.